# Como determinar o tamanho de uma JTextField?

Tags: java

Estou fazendo um programa envolvendo teorema de pitágoras, e queria deixar um triangulo no meio, com três JTextField em volta dos três lados dele. Fiz isso, mas o problema é que quando eu crio o JTextField e adiciono ele para o Container desejado, ele fica imenso. É um retângulo branco muito grande que quando eu clico para digitar, sai uma letra pequena. Por tanto, minha pergunta é: Como posso mudar o tamanho desse JTextField para diminui-lo e evitar tamanhos desnecessários?

Comment: OBS.: Estou usando a biblioteca Swing e AWT mesmo!!

Comment: Qual é o Layout do content pane que está o seu JTextField? Exemplo: BorderLayout, MigLayout, GridBagLayout...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tente usar o `setBounds`, veja [aqui](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setBounds(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)).

Exemplo:

```
public void teste()
    {
        //posição da caixa de texto no eixo horizontal em pixeis 
        int posX = 10;

        //posição da caixa de texto no eixo vertical em pixeis 
        int posY = 10;

        //largura da caixa de texto em pixeis
        int largura = 10;

         //altura da caixa de texto em pixeis
        int altura = 10;
        //é necessário instanciar antes o objecto
        JTextField cxaTexto = new JTextField();

        cxaTexto.setBounds(posX, posY, largura, altura);
    }
```

Comment: Tente postar um exemplo prático em código usando a sua solução, não apenas postar uma refência

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada.

Comment: Na minha opinião postar um exemplo irá tornar desnecessário colocar a referência e vice-versa, mas não tem makas, vou fazer o update da resposta mano.

Comment: @Caputo, obrigado pela explanação, captei.